# Cookies are not set/stored in iOS with WKWebEngine

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Since we upgraded from the old `UIWebView` engine, we are not able to authenticate our users (using an external auth service), as none of the cookies sent by the APIs are being set in the this web view.

This is a major blocker for us and have been trying to determine what a good course of action is. If our assumptions are correct that cookies are not supported with this web view (which is very strange), we are going to try:

- Proxy (not sure if you recommend a good plugin for this)
- Native fetch (not sure if you recommend a good plugin for this)

Our stack:

- Cordova
- React
- Fetch for calls

Comment: I have the same issue since I upgraded to `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` (https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) :(

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12074

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the link. The issue though is that it's not only on first app launch for me! :( I tried already all the suggested plugins that solve the issue for the first app launch.

Comment: I think you can use localStorage to store your cookies as an alternative. Not saying that it is good but it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try rolling back to the previous one

Comment: It is very slow and has shallow security (it does not even enforce CORS policies).